# How To Pass ImageView With Key With The Help Of Bundle

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I'm using Firebase to retrieve realtime data . I wants to display an image, title and description with the use of bundle. So here is my code. Title and Description are reflected in a good manner but the image is not loading on the device. How can I resolve this?

```
package com.mypackage.cardstack.fragment;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.mypackage.cardstack.R;

public class CardStackFragment extends Fragment {


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
        final Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e("TGA", "Clikced on " + bundle.getString("TITLE"));

            }
        });
        TextView t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView d = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.desc1);
        ImageView m=(ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fish);

        t.setText(bundle.getString("TITLE"));
        d.setText(bundle.getString("DESC"));
        m.setImageResource(bundle.getInt("IMAGE"));


        return rootView;
    }

    public static CardStackFragment getFragment(String title, String desc,String image) {
        CardStackFragment cardStackFragment = new CardStackFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("TITLE", title);
        args.putString("DESC", desc);
        args.putString("IMAGE",image);
        cardStackFragment.setArguments(args);
        return cardStackFragment;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are putting the Image Source into the Bundle as a String, and then reading it back as an Int.... I think you want to save the Image resource ID (R.drawable.yourImage, for example) into the bundle. This is an integer. You should be able to getInt() to retrieve it.

Comment: I can't store the image in drawable folder as I wants to retrieve the image from the firebase. @Mike

Comment: What is contained in "String image" ? Is this the URL to the Firebase image? You could pass that as String in the Bundle, and getString, not Int, in the receiving Fragment, then let the Fragment download from Firebase using that URL.

Comment: If I write "getString" instead of "getInt" then it shows an error that it requires an int , not string. @Mike

Answer (score 0):

Convert image downloaded to byte array and send it to the main activity

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    if(bitmap!=null) {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();  
        bundle.putByteArray("your key string", byteArray);

}
```

Similarly in main activity retrieve it as

```
 byte[] data= message.getData().getByteArray(key);                                               
 Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);
                    imageView= findViewById(R.id.largeImage);
                    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Also make sure that you make your image view as visible in main activity.

Comment: @JoeMayo  What is The term "message" here? Its giving an error

Comment: That's @Sunilkumar More 's answer - I just edited it to fix code formatting.

Comment: @SunilkumarMore What is "message" here? Its giving an error

Comment: Instanciate a class Message message = new Message();
This class Defines a message containing a description and arbitrary data object that can be sent to a Handler.  Please reefer to below documentation.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html